# Split and add text/number to the filename

Tags: powershell, split, rename, trim, file-manipulation

I have been trying to write a script to remove end part of the filename and replace it with a version number of a build. I have tried trim and split but because of extra dots and not good with regex, im having problems.

These are file examples:

```
Filename.Api.sow.0.1.1856.nupkg
something.Customer.Web.0.1.1736.nupkg
```

I want to remove `0.1.18xx` from these filenames and add a build number from variable. which would be something like `1.0.1234.1233` (major.minor.build.revision)

so the end result should be:

```
Filename.Api.sow.1.0.1234.1233.nupkg
something.Customer.Web.1.0.112.342.nupkg
```

Here is my try to split and then rename. But it doesnt work.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | where {! $_.PSIsContainer}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$name,$version = $file.Name.Split('[0-9]',2)
Rename-Item -NewName "$name$version" "$name".$myvariableforbuild
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Here a solution with regex:

```
$myVariableForBuild = '1.0.1234.1233'
Get-ChildItem 'c:\your_path' -Recurse | 
    where {! $_.PSIsContainer} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '\d+\.\d+\.\d+$', $myVariableForBuild) + $_.Extension }
```

Comment: you can remove your  where if you specify -file in gci

Comment: @Esperento57 He is also using `PsIsContainer` in his code so he most likely uses PowerShell-v2 where the `-file` switch is missing. So I probably *can't remove the where* here.

Comment: he doesn't specify his version. May be he dont know -file too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most concise way to do it, but I would split the string based on ".", get the last element of the array (the file extension), then iterate through each array element. If its non-numeric append it to a new string, if numeric break the loop. Then append the new version and file extension to the new string.

```
$str = "something.Customer.Web.0.1.1736.nupkg"
$arr = $str.Split(".")

$extension = $arr[$arr.Count - 1]
$filename = ""
$newversion = "1.0.112.342"

for ($i = 0 - 1; $i -lt $arr.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($arr[$i] -notmatch "^[\d\.]+$")
    {
        # item is not numeric - add to string
        $filename += $arr[$i] + "."
    }
    else
    {
        # item is numeric - end loop
        break
    }    
}

# add the new version
$filename += $newversion + "."

# add the extension
$filename += $extension
```

Obviously its not a complete solution to your problem, but there is enough there for you to get going.